# VALGRIND: How to use valgrind for ".so" library?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, valgrind

Do i need to use valgrind on each program file with which ".so" is made.. or is there any we can run valgrind directly on ".so" library. please provide steps for later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not directly. Library does not have an entry point where to start executing it, and *valgrind* only checks code that is actually executing.

Still, if you want to test a library with *valgrind*, there is a simple way. Just write a test program, which uses the library in the way that tests the parts and features of library you want tested. Then *valgrind* that.

It is probably better to write several small test programs to test different features and use patterns, instead if one big one which tries to test everything in one execution (easier to isolate any problem *valgrind* finds, faster to run).

Answer (score 5):

Valgrind watches upon code that being executed. Shared library is never executed unless some program uses them. If some code never executed, valgrind will never notice it.